# ORB SLAM2 build error with eigen3

Tags: eigen3

I am trying to build `ORBSLAM2` but i always get some errors. I don't know the reason. I am pasting command line output. How can I solve the errors? has someone done this before?

```css
orbslam@essafius-Latitude-E6430:~$ cd ORB_SLAM2
orbslam@essafius-Latitude-E6430:~/ORB_SLAM2$ chmod +x build.sh
orbslam@essafius-Latitude-E6430:~/ORB_SLAM2$ ./build.sh
Configuring and building Thirdparty/DBoW2 ...
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘build’: File exists
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/orbslam/ORB_SLAM2/Thirdparty/DBoW2/build
[100%] Built target DBoW2
Configuring and building Thirdparty/g2o ...
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘build’: File exists
-- BUILD TYPE:Release
-- Compiling on Unix
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/orbslam/ORB_SLAM2/Thirdparty/g2o/build
[100%] Built target g2o
Uncompress vocabulary ...
Configuring and building ORB_SLAM2 ...
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘build’: File exists
Build type: Release
-- Using flag -std=c++11.
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/orbslam/ORB_SLAM2/build
[  3%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ORB_SLAM2.dir/src/Tracking.cc.o
[  6%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ORB_SLAM2.dir/src/LoopClosing.cc.o
[  9%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ORB_SLAM2.dir/src/Viewer.cc.o
[ 12%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ORB_SLAM2.dir/src/System.cc.o
[ 15%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ORB_SLAM2.dir/src/LocalMapping.cc.o
In file included from /home/orbslam/ORB_SLAM2/Thirdparty/g2o/g2o/types/types_seven_dof_expmap.h:34:0,
                 from /home/orbslam/ORB_SLAM2/include/LoopClosing.h:34,
                 from /home/orbslam/ORB_SLAM2/include/LocalMapping.h:26,
                 from /home/orbslam/ORB_SLAM2/include/Tracking.h:31,
                 from /home/orbslam/ORB_SLAM2/include/FrameDrawer.h:24,
                 from /home/orbslam/ORB_SLAM2/include/Viewer.h:25,
                 from /home/orbslam/ORB_SLAM2/src/Viewer.cc:21:
/home/orbslam/ORB_SLAM2/Thirdparty/g2o/g2o/types/../core/base_vertex.h:62:74: warning: ‘Eigen::AlignedBit’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     typedef Eigen::Map<Matrix<double, D, D>, Matrix<double,D,D>::Flags & AlignedBit ? Aligned : Unaligned >  HessianBlockType;
```

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/raulmur/ORB_SLAM2/issues/317

^Their github log is good for solving common issues, It seems you are having an issue with your Eigen version, get an older one and recompile everything.